# Calculate shift timings in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I have two tables. One with start date and end date of certain jobs and another table with shift timings . This is the structure of Shift table

**Job Table**

```
Job_ID            Start_Time          End_Time
1           01.12.2013 16:38:56     09.12.2013 10:38:56
2           11.11.2013 10:14:13     07.12.2013 12:28:26
3           29.11.2013 08:20:22     05.12.2013 07:18:17
```

**Shift Data Table**

```
Start      End        Day
    0:00    6:00:00   Monday
 6:00:00   12:00:00   Monday
12:00:00    0:00:00   Tuesday
 0:00:00    6:00:00   Wednesday
 6:00:00   12:00:00   Saturday
 6:00:00   12:00:00   Sunday
```

**Expected output**

```
Job_ID            Start_Time          End_Time             Shift Timings
1           01.12.2013 16:38:56     09.12.2013 10:38:56      1   18:00:00
```

eg: From the time job started at '01.12.2013 16:38:56' until it got closed at '09.12.2013 10:38:56', there was a total of 42 hours shift timing (which is calculated as interval value) as per the slot table. I hope my requirement clear.

For each row of Job entry with start time and end time, I need to calculate how much Shift time was involved.

Comment: Please post your tries.

Comment: Post the sample data for both the tables and the expected output too.

Comment: "From the time job started at ' 01.12.2013 16:38:56' until it got closed at ' 09.12.2013 10:38:56', there was a total of 42 hours shift timing" - are you sure about this? There is much more then 42 hours interval between this two dates.

Comment: When you write a question make sure that you speak about effective timings rather than elapsed timings for more clarity.
For any jobid you need to 
1) find the days between the date range 
2) Assuming on any give day, the work will be carried out strictly by the shift table
3) Once we derive the number of days and their shift timings on that particular day, we must calculate the elapsed timing (which is 42 for the first job)
4) BUT WHERE ON EARTH YOU GET Shift and Timings calculated as 1 and 18:00:00

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is:

1) A job is a time interval, and you need to generate 1 tuple for each day. If a job start today and ends tomorrow you need 2 tuples (today and tomorrow dates). You can do this with:

```
SELECT JOBID, 
    GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART,
    LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, 
    NDAY 
FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL NDAY 
    FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)
    ), JOBS 
WHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= 
    LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))
```

2) You have to fix SHIFT table (on some tuples ending time is 0:00:00, this is the hour of the next day). You can use:

```
SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET
FROM SHIFTS
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
UNION
SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET
FROM SHIFTS
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

This select includes a SHIFTENDOFFSET
: 0 if the hour is in the starting day and 1 if the hour is in the day after the starting day.

3) Now you can join both using the day of SHIFTS and the day of “every job day”, and filter impossible tuples (those days when the job begins after the shift ends)

```
SELECT JOBID, 
    GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART), 
    LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND), 
    24*(LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)) TOTAL
FROM
    (SELECT JOBID, GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART, LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, NDAY FROM (SELECT LEVEL NDAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)), JOBS wHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))) 
    JOIN
    (SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') UNION SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
    ON (TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART, 'Day','nls_date_language=english') LIKE (DAY||'%'))
WHERE LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND)
    > GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

4) group by JOBID and SUM to get the total hours.

```
SELECT JOBID, 
    24*SUM(LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)) TOTAL
FROM
    (SELECT JOBID, GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART, LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, NDAY FROM (SELECT LEVEL NDAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)), JOBS WHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))) 
    JOIN
    (SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') UNION SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
    ON (TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART, 'Day','nls_date_language=english') LIKE (DAY||'%'))
WHERE LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) > GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)
GROUP BY JOBID
```

5) And finally, apply your expected output format:

`SELECT JOBID "Job_ID", JOBSTART "Start_Time", JOBEND "End_Time", TRUNC(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)))||'   '|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)),1)*24),'FM00')||':'|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(MOD(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)),1)*24,1)*60),'FM00')||':'|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(MOD(MOD(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)),1)*24,1)*60,1)*60),'FM00') "Shift Timings" FROM (SELECT JOBID, JOBSTART, JOBEND, GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART, LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, NDAY FROM (SELECT LEVEL NDAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)), JOBS WHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))) JOIN (SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') UNION SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ) ON (TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART, 'Day','nls_date_language=english') LIKE (DAY||'%')) WHERE LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) > GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART) GROUP BY JOBID, JOBSTART, JOBEND`

In your example you say that job 1 accumulate 42 hours, but this is not correct. Job 1 has more than 52 hours. Job 3 has 42 hours.

You can use the following script (it creates JOBS and SHIFTS tables, introduces your samples rows and perform 3), 4) and 5) queries):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS DAY';

DROP TABLE JOBS;

DROP TABLE SHIFTS;

CREATE TABLE JOBS
 (JOBID NUMBER, JOBSTART DATE, JOBEND DATE);

CREATE TABLE SHIFTS
 (SHIFTSTART VARCHAR2(8), SHIFTEND VARCHAR2(8), DAY VARCHAR2(13));

INSERT INTO JOBS VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01.12.2013 16:38:56','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('09.12.2013 10:38:56','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

INSERT INTO JOBS VALUES (2, TO_DATE('11.11.2013 10:14:13','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('07.12.2013 12:28:26','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

INSERT INTO JOBS VALUES (3, TO_DATE('29.11.2013 08:20:22','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('05.12.2013 07:18:17','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));


-- Fix the start hour to 0:00:00 instead of 0:00

INSERT INTO SHIFTS VALUES ('0:0:00','6:00:00','Monday');

INSERT INTO SHIFTS VALUES ('6:00:00','12:00:00','Monday');

INSERT INTO SHIFTS VALUES ('12:00:00','0:00:00','Tuesday');

INSERT INTO SHIFTS VALUES ('0:00:00','6:00:00','Wednesday');

INSERT INTO SHIFTS VALUES ('6:00:00','12:00:00','Saturday');

INSERT INTO SHIFTS VALUES ('6:00:00','12:00:00','Sunday');

COMMIT;

SELECT JOBID, GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
JOBDAYSTART), LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND), 24*(
LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
JOBDAYSTART)) TOTAL
FROM
(SELECT JOBID, GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART, LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, NDAY
FROM (SELECT LEVEL NDAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)), JOBS
WHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))) 
JOIN
(SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET
FROM SHIFTS
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
UNION
SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET
FROM SHIFTS
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
) 
ON (TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART, 'Day','nls_date_language=english') LIKE (DAY||'%'))
WHERE LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) > GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
JOBDAYSTART)
ORDER BY 1,2;

SELECT JOBID, 24*SUM(
LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
JOBDAYSTART)) TOTAL
FROM
(SELECT JOBID, GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART, LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, NDAY
FROM (SELECT LEVEL NDAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)), JOBS
WHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))) 
JOIN
(SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET
FROM SHIFTS
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
UNION
SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET
FROM SHIFTS
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
) 
ON (TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART, 'Day','nls_date_language=english') LIKE (DAY||'%'))
WHERE LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) > GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
JOBDAYSTART)
GROUP BY JOBID;

SELECT JOBID "Job_ID", JOBSTART "Start_Time", JOBEND "End_Time", TRUNC(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)))||'   '|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)),1)*24),'FM00')||':'|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(MOD(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)),1)*24,1)*60),'FM00')||':'|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(MOD(MOD(SUM( LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) - GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART)),1)*24,1)*60,1)*60),'FM00') "Shift Timings" FROM (SELECT JOBID, JOBSTART, JOBEND, GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) JOBDAYSTART, LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD')) JOBDAYEND, NDAY FROM (SELECT LEVEL NDAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT CEIL(MAX(JOBEND - JOBSTART))+1 FROM JOBS)), JOBS WHERE GREATEST(JOBSTART, TRUNC(JOBSTART+(NDAY-1),'DDD')) <= LEAST(JOBEND, TRUNC(JOBEND+NDAY,'DDD'))) JOIN (SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 0 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') UNION SELECT SHIFTSTART, SHIFTEND, DAY, 1 SHIFTENDOFFSET FROM SHIFTS WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ) ON (TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART, 'Day','nls_date_language=english') LIKE (DAY||'%')) WHERE LEAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTEND,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + SHIFTENDOFFSET, JOBDAYEND) > GREATEST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(JOBDAYSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD ') || SHIFTSTART,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), JOBDAYSTART) GROUP BY JOBID, JOBSTART, JOBEND;
```